# Add custom metadata to video using AVFoundation

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation

I want to add some info (metadata) to a video. I have found a way to retrieve metadata, but did not find any solution to set or modify metadata. I am using `AVURLAsset`, `AVAssetWritter` also `AVMutableComposition` for creating the video.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`-[AVAssetWriter setMetadata:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetWriter_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAssetWriter/metadata).

This is set to an `NSArray` of `AVMutableMetadataItem`s. Note that you cannot set the value after writing has started.

Metadata keys and keyspaces are listed in `AVMetadataFormat.h`.

Answer (score 1):

When using `AVMutableComposition`, you can set the `metadata` property on the `AVAssetExportSession` when you go to write it out, rather than setting it on the asset (the composition) itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do it "off line". I've used the id3taggenerator and related tools and they work great.

Checkout more info here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming/UsingHTTPLiveStreaming.html

Or here's a tutorial I used for adding timed metadata that's pretty good:
http://jmacmullin.wordpress.com/2010/11/03/adding-meta-data-to-video-in-ios/

If you want to add meta data in-app (as in a user records a video and add's their own meta data) I'm not sure there.

Comment: Thanks, But i am looking answer for "as in a user records a video and add's their own meta data)"

Answer (score -2):

Check out gusutils ==>

https://github.com/gpambrozio/GusUtils

There is an xcode project for creating a static library that lets you add metadata and geolocation information to your video and then persist to the assets library.