# Regarding rotation information when rotating a movie in Avfoundation

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I was able to rotate the movie with the following code

```
videoCompositionTrack.preferredTransform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(M_PI_2))
```

I confirmed the information of the rotated video by ffmpeg. Rotate in the tag does not fluctuate as shown below, but a tag called side_data_list was generated and the value of rotation in side_data_list fluctuated, while keeping the information of rotate in tag unchanged.I want to change "tag" information.

```
"tags": {
                "rotate": "90"
        },
"side_data_list": [
                {
"rotation": -90
                }
```

Are there any good advice on AVFoundation and ffmpeg?

Comment: Might be useful to tell us whether this is macOS or iOS.

Comment: Also, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10480991/add-custom-metadata-to-video-using-avfoundation - unclear what all this has to do with ffmpeg, since you are apparently merely using it as a window into the metadata.

Comment: this is iOS And This is all sources of my video rotation. https://github.com/Ryosuke-Hujisawa/Video-rotation-swift3

Comment: The command that confirmed the information about the outputted video is the following command.  ffprobe -show_streams -print_format json rendered-audio.m4v 2>/dev/nul

Comment: Right, but you didn't do that within iOS so it's kind of irrelevant; you stepped into another universe in order to see the metadata. :) I mean, you're not going to use ffmpeg to _set_ the tags, so this is not a question about ffmpeg at all; it's a question about how to set the tags.